# Kingston USB flash drive fails to eject. MacBook Pro, High Sierra

Tags: mac, usb

I use several Kingston 64GB flash drives. On occasion, they won't eject, even when every app is quit. Is there a sudo command to make a flash drive eject?

Comment: Finder should give you a force eject option once it times out. Are you not seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal type **diskutil list** To list all connected drives. Then determine which of the drives mounted are the device you want to eject.  For example if it is /dev/disk2 Then type **diskutil eject /dev/disk2** It should eject the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Also found another option, doesn't require using Terminal.
Open Activity Monitor in All Processes/Disk
find QuickLookUIService
tap the x box in upper Left corner of window
you may be asked to Force Quit and then choose that